# Classes variables are deleted automatically after leaving the scope, how do i prevent that from happening?

Tags: c++, class, object, dynamic-memory-allocation, calling-convention

I'm having an issue when calling a classes (class A) function from another classes (class B) function where the variables from the class i am trying to call (class A) which are constructed in that class are deleted after the function is completed and returned to the function from which I am calling from (class C). What is happening and how do I fix this?

Ive tried using pointers to that class and dynamically allocating the entire class but the variables are still deleted.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

class A {

private:

    vector<string> vectorA;
    string stringA[5] = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
    string stringB[5] = { "6", "7", "8", "9" };

public:


    string generaterandnum() {
        int num1 = NULL;
        num1 = rand() % vectorA.size();
        string card = vectorA[num1];
        vectorA.erase(vectorA.begin() + num1);
        return card;
    }


    void buildvectorA()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                vectorA.push_back(stringA[j] + stringB[i]);
            }
        }
        return;
    }
};

class B {
private:
    vector<string>  vectorB;
    vector<string>  vectorC;

    A aobject;

public:

    void buildvectorBandC() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            vectorB.push_back(aobject.generaterandnum());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            vectorC.push_back(aobject.generaterandnum());
        }
    }

    void displayvector() {
        cout << "Vector: ";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < vectorB.size(); i++) {
            cout << "[" << vectorB[i] << "] (" << i << ") ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};

    class C {
        friend int main();
        void programrun(int option) {
            A* a = new A;
            a->buildvectorA();
            B* b = new B;

            if (option == 0) {
                cout << "Here is the vector that just has been constructed" << endl;
                b->buildvectorBandC();
                while (true) {
                    b->displayvector();

                }
            }
        }
    };

    int main() {
        srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
        cout << "Hello" << endl;
        cout << "Enter (R) to run the program." << endl;
        char input;
        while (true) {
            cin >> input;
            input = toupper(input);
            if (input == 'R') {
                C cobject;
                cobject.programrun(0);
                return false;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Invalid input" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

I expected to build vector B and C with randomly generated numbers that pick the variables from vectorA. But what I got was when it gets to generaterandnum() it displays an error saying Unhandled exception at 0x00F1C77F in Project1.exe: 0xC0000094: Integer division by zero. because vectorA has a size of 0 because it was deleted after the program left the scope of that class.

Comment: You want `new` and allocate objects on the heap if you want them to outlive a scope. Please don't use raw `new` though; use smart pointers.

Comment: Just nitpicking here, but `NULL` is for null *pointers* (inherited from C). C++ doesn't have the concept of "null" values.

Comment: Your mistake is thinking that non-static data members belong to a class.  That's not true.  Every instance of the class has its own independent copy of all non-static data members.  (In fact, that's the entire distinction between `static` and non-static data members)

Comment: I had a problem with static members before. If i turn something into a static member, I will have to turn my entire program into static members variables and functions declaring them outside of the class which makes classes useless.

Answer (score 1):

Class members live as long as your class objects do. The problem is not with object lifetime, but with the fact that `B::aobject` is has never had `buildvectorA` called, so it's `vectorA` is empty, so `vectorA.size() == 0`. You then try to calculate `rand() % vectorA.size()`, and (integer) division by `0` is a pretty bad idea.

You may want to create a constuctor for `A` and call the `generaterandnum` there to make sure it's always proper:

```
class A {

private:
    vector<string> vectorA;
    string stringA[5] = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
    string stringB[5] = { "6", "7", "8", "9" };

    void buildvectorA()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                vectorA.push_back(stringA[j] + stringB[i]);
            }
        }
    }

public:
    A() {
        buildvectorA();
    }

    string generaterandnum() {
        int num1 = NULL;
        num1 = rand() % vectorA.size();
        string card = vectorA[num1];
        vectorA.erase(vectorA.begin() + num1);
        return card;
    }
};
```

---

Note that `buildvectorA` is now private method. We don't want anyone from outside to call it, because they don't care how are the random numbers generated. They just want to get those random numbers.

This also means that your class `C` doesn't need to call `buildvectorA`, and in fact, it doesn't even need to have any object `A`.